# Nodemailer's sendMail function returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Hi!

I have the following code. The commented lined never get executed and `info.response` returns "undefined". Could you help me figure out why it's returning "undefined" and why the commented parts don't get executed, please?

Thank you very much.

**app.js:**

```javascript
app.get('/send', function (req, res) {
  var mailOptions = {
    from: req.query.from,
    to: 'chul@stackexchange.com',
    subject: 'Applicant',
    text: req.query.name + req.query.content
  };
  console.log(mailOptions);
  transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.end("error");
    } else {
      console.log("Message sent: " + info.repsonse);
      res.end("sent"); // This part does NOT get executed.
    };
  });
});
```

**index.html:**

```javascript
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var from, name, content;
      $("#send_app").click(function() {
        from = $("#from").val();
        name = $("#name").val();
        content = $("#content").val();
        $("message").text("Submitting the application ...");
        $.get("http://localhost:3000/send", {
          from: from,
          name: name,
          content: content
        }, function(data) {
          if (data == "sent") { // This block does NOT get executed
            console.log("sent received");
            $("#message").empty().html("The e-mail has been sent.");
          } else {
            console.log(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: I'm using nodemailer 1.0. Could it be why? When I was using 0.7 it was fine ...

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, I don't see see the initialization of the transport. Try something like:

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'SendGrid',
  auth: {
    user: yourUserName,
    pass: yourPassword
  }
});
// Then the transport you initialized
var mailOptions = {
    from: req.query.from,
    to: 'chul@stackexchange.com',
    subject: 'Applicant',
    text: req.query.name + req.query.content
 };
console.log(mailOptions);
transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
   if (error) {
     console.log(error);
     res.end("error");
   } else {
     console.log("Message sent: " + info.repsonse);
     res.end("sent"); // This part does NOT get executed.
  };
});
```

Comment: Hi Stephen. Thank you for the reply! I didn't include other parts of my code in this e-mail to avoid cluttering. I used the direct transport (via port 25).. I think I figured out why though. I'll get back after work today :) Thank you

Comment: @ChulKwon Have fun at work. When you get home, what's the console for index.html logging? Also, are you trying to fire the email on a get request, and not a post?

Comment: yep, I was using get request b/c that's what the Nodemailer doc recommended. I figured out why though. It looks like there was another breaking change when Nodemailer went from 1.0 (when the doc was written) to 1.3.2.

Comment: So can you post your resolution? I'm experiencing this issue.

Comment: Did you get solution ?

Comment: Please write the solution, experiencing the same issue.

Comment: any solution, facing the same issue?